# Switching div block to visible why design becomes broken?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In laravel 5, jquery 3, "bootstrap 4.4, blade app 
I have some blocks invisible by default

```
<div class="form-row m-0 p-0" id="div_checking_step_2_recurring_rent" style="display: none; border: 2px dotted blue;">
    <label for="numeric_step_2_recurring_rent" class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-form-label" style="border: 2px dotted yellow;">Rent</label>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
        {!! $viewFuncs->text('numeric_step_2_recurring_rent', '', "form-control editable_field", ["maxlength"=>"255",
        "autocomplete"=>"off", "style"=>"border: 2px dotted green;" ] )      !!}
        <input type="text" id="step_2_recurring_rent" name="step_2_recurring_rent" value="0" style="visibility: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px">
    </div>
</div>
```

and they becomes visible only when user clciks ckheckbox. That is done with method:

```
bookingsAndAvailability.prototype.is_recurringOnChange = function () {
    var is_recurring= $("#step_2_recurring_is_recurring:checked").val()
    if (is_recurring) {
        $("#div_checking_step_2_recurring_rent").css("display", "block")
    } else {
        $("#div_checking_step_2_recurring_rent").css("display", "none")
    }

}
```

And the problem is when method above is triggered and div_checking_step_2_recurring_rent becomes visible

then label and div inside of div_checking_step_2_recurring_rent are not on 1 line, but div is below of label,

```
If style="display: none;"
```

is removed from the code above then
label and div inside of div_checking_step_2_recurring_rent ARE on 1 line.

What did I miss in bookingsAndAvailability.prototype.is_recurringOnChange method ?

Thanks!

Comment: `display: none` will make it so the div no longer takes up space in the document, so then the document will re-flow and could mess up your layout. You can try using `.css("opacity", "1")` (to show) and `.css("opacity", "0")` (to hide). This will make it "invisible" but still allow the div to take up space in the document so no re-flow will happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap I believe it is defaulting to `display: flex;` so when you simply remove the `display: none;` it is not set to to `display: block` its set to `display: flex;`. Which is why it works when you remove that code.

When you toggle it with your js you are setting it to block.  I'd recommend using your js to set it to flex. Like this:

```
bookingsAndAvailability.prototype.is_recurringOnChange = function () {
    var is_recurring= $("#step_2_recurring_is_recurring:checked").val()
    if (is_recurring) {
        $("#div_checking_step_2_recurring_rent").css("display", "flex")
    } else {
        $("#div_checking_step_2_recurring_rent").css("display", "none")
    }

}
```

I hope this helps.